# jQuery .rules() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have yet another issue with the `.rules(`) function to add to the pile. I have the understanding that it is supposed to come after using `.validate()`, yet I receive a 'cannot find settings' type error in my console anyway.

The reason I do not add it as a rule inside the `.validate()` is because I have multiple forms on a page, some of which use the have inputs that use the same name (they are submitted with AJAX, name fields point to my DDB columns).

Code below. Any ideas?

```
<form id="userForm" class='validate form-horizontal'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">Not a member yet?</legend>

        <input type="hidden" name="User_ID" id="User_ID">
        <input type="hidden" name="PermissionLevel" id="PermissionLevel" value="1">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="RegisterUserName">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="UserName" id="RegisterUserName" class="required email form-control tooltip-toggle" title="This will be your username" data-placement="right">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="RegisterUserPassword">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="UserPassword" id="RegisterUserPassword" class="required password form-control tooltip-toggle" title="Your password must be between 8-14 characters and can only contain numbers, letters, and the following symbols: @ * _ - . !" data-placement="right" rangelength="[8,14]">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="RegisterUserPassword2">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="UserPassword2" id="RegisterUserPassword2" class="required password form-control" rangelength="[8,14]">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-register form-submit" data-form="registerUsername">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```js
$('form.validate').each(function() {
  $(this).validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'has-error help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if ($(element).hasClass('chosen-select') || $(element).hasClass('chosen-select-multiple')) {
      error.appendTo(element.next('.chosen-container'));
      } else {
        element.after(error);
      }
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      if ($(element).hasClass('chosen-select') || $(element).hasClass('chosen-select-multiple')) {
        $(element).next('.chosen-container').find('a').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      }
      $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      if ($(element).hasClass('chosen-select') || $(element).hasClass('chosen-select-multiple')) {
        $(element).next('.chosen-container').find('a').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
      }
      $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    ignore: ':hidden:not(.chosen-select):not(.chosen-select-multiple)'
  });

  $.validator.addMethod('USAdate', function(value, element, param) {
    var isValidDate = /^((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|((2|02)[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9]))))[\/]\d{4}$|^\d{4}$/.test(value);
    return this.optional(element) || isValidDate;
  }, 'Please enter a valid date.');

  $.validator.addMethod('phone', function(value, element, param) {
    var isValidPhone = /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(value);
    return this.optional(element) || isValidPhone;
  }, 'Please enter a valid phone number.');

  $.validator.addMethod('password', function(value, element, param) {
    var isValidPassword = /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]+$/.test(value);
    return this.optional(element) || isValidPassword;
  }, 'Must be between 8-14 characters, only numbers, letters, and the following symbols: @ * _ - . !');

  $.validator.addMethod('nnInteger', function(value, element, param) {
    var isNNInteger = /^\d+$/.test(value);
    return this.optional(element) || isNNInteger;
  }, 'Please enter a non-negative number.');

  $('#RegisterUserPassword2').rules('add', {
    equalTo: '#RegisterUserPassword',
    messages: {
      equalTo: 'Passwords must match.'
    }
  });
});

$('.form-submit').on('click', function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');

  switch ($(this).data('form')) {
    case 'registerUsername':
    var loginModal = $('#login');
    var registerModal = $('#register');

    if (form.validate().form()) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/ajax/ajax-registerUsername.php',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.result === 'error') {
            loginModal.find('.modal-header').addClass('error');
            loginModal.find('.modal-footer').addClass('error').html('Error: An error occured while submitting your username<br>' + data.message);
            return false;
          } else {
            console.log(data);
            clientRegistration = data.user;
            loginModal.modal('hide');
            var registerCarousel = registerModal.find('#registerCarousel');
            registerModal.modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}, 'show');
          }
        }
      });
    }
    break;
  }
});
```

Edit: simply commenting out the `.rules()` call removes the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` error.

Edit 2: wrapped form validation as suggested, added one example of form submission.

Comment: There is no issue with the latest version of the code as you've posted it:  http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution. If you're running a `$.each()` to validate multiple forms at once, specifically if more than one form is present on a given page, you can't add a rule using `.rules()` more than once.

```
$('form.validate').each(function() {
  //.validate() stuff here
  switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'userForm':
      $('#RegisterUserPassword2').rules('add', {
        equalTo: '#RegisterUserPassword',
        messages: {
          equalTo: 'Passwords must match.'
        }
      });
      break;
    case 'passForm':
      $('#NewPassword2').rules('add', {
        equalTo: '#NewPassword',
        messages: {
          equalTo: 'Passwords must match.'
        }
      });
      break;
  }
});
```

Something like that can be used to add the rule for the given form that input belongs to. Not the best programmatic method, but it works.

Comment: **Quote**:  *"If you're running a `$.each()` to validate multiple forms at once, specifically if more than one form is present on a given page, you can't add a rule using `.rules()` more than once"*  ~ This is simply not true:   http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/1/

Comment: @Sparky: I'm not going to get into a silly flame war with you. This solution works for me, whether you accept it or not. Deal with it.

Comment: Relax, this is not a "flame-war", nor is there anything silly about helping other people by pointing out that the statement in your answer is technically incorrect as proven by this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/1/  ~ As far as helping you specifically, I spent considerable amounts of time with an OP that was constantly edited and yet working all along:   http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/  ~ To get help, the burden is on you to post code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

```
$('form.validate').validate({
    onsubmit: true, 
    ....
```

[Check the docs regarding `onsubmit: true` - *"A boolean true is **not** a valid value."*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit)   In other words, you can only set `onsubmit` to `false` or a function.  Just leave it out entirely if you want the default functionality.

By setting it `true`, you will likely break the plugin.

---

To have validation occur immediately when the button is clicked, you must have a `type="submit"` on your `button` element.  (*Or a `click` handler containing code that programmatically triggers validation.*)

---

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rma3s6n0/**

---

**EDIT**:

> ...because I have side-by-side forms that use the same name...
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` error.

Apparently you're trying to attach the `.validate()` method to more than one `form` by targeting a class...

```
$('form.validate').validate({ ...
```

If so, then **you MUST use a jQuery `.each()` to attach the method to more than one form element**, thereby initializing each form separately.   [This is a documented limitation of the plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page).

```
$('form.validate').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({ ....
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

The OP was edited to the point where the issues above no longer appear in the code.

I see you edited the question again.  Your ajax form submission code should be contained within the `submitHandler` callback function.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler

> *"The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"*

---

**EDIT 3**:

[As of the time of this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35510283/4), the OP's code is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/

Comment: Removing that line has made no difference. The plugin functions the same regardless. I know it has to do with adding rules, because commenting it out removes my error.

Comment: @Shaazaam, your code is working for me without any errors:  http://jsfiddle.net/L74emvku/

Comment: @Shaazaam, also, to have validation occur immediately when the button is clicked, you must have a `type="submit"` on your `button` element.

Comment: I validate it using `.validate().form()` before I send it off. Very curious that it works in your Fiddle. I am using 1.14 as well. I wonder if having more than one form present is effecting it. All other parts of the plugin function fine with or without attempting to add that rule.

Comment: changes made, still no difference. Logging  usage of #RegisterUserName2 yields only the one instance of that ID.

Comment: @Shaazaam, I'll stop now as I think otherwise this back & forth will never end.  I'm going to leave you with one last edit to my answer.   Good luck.

Comment: I disagree with your last edit. The plugin doesn't need to concern itself with form submission, I have more dedicated means to do that. Furthermore there are a few simple forms that do not get submitted with AJAX. It's unfortunate another set of eyes could not determine the issue.

Comment: @Shaazaam, if you disagree with my last edit, then you disagree with the developer's own documentation.  Regardless, [your code as you posted it is still working](http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/), so the only set of eyes that can possibly see the issue are your own:  http://jsfiddle.net/r0fd80hb/